# Multiple auth user types in Laravel 5

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

How can I separate auth user group into 3 groups, I need admin, client and worker group.

Here is my route for auth users:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){

    Route::get('home', array(
        'as' => 'home',
        'uses'  => 'HomeController@index'
        ));


    Route::get('logout', array(
       'as' => 'logout',
       'uses' => 'UserController@logout'
    ));


});
```

Answer (score 4):

I've written a middleware that can do basic role based authentication, as you've described.

```
Route::get('home', [
     'middleware' => ['auth', 'roles'], //use the roles middleware
     'uses' => 'HomeController@index',
     'roles' => ['admin', 'client'] // only admin and client roles are allowed
]);
```

### Instructions

In App\Http\Middleware, create a file called 'CheckRole.php'

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;
// First copy this file into your middleware directoy
use Closure;
class CheckRole{
/**
* Handle an incoming request.
*
* @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
* @param \Closure $next
* @return mixed
*/
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // Get the required roles from the route
    $roles = $this->getRequiredRoleForRoute($request->route());
    // Check if a role is required for the route, and
    // if so, ensure that the user has that role.
    if($request->user()->hasRole($roles) || !$roles)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }
    return response([
        'error' => [
        'code' => 'INSUFFICIENT_ROLE',
        'description' => 'You are not authorized to access this  resource.'
    ]
    ], 401);
    }
    private function getRequiredRoleForRoute($route)
    {
        $actions = $route->getAction();
        return isset($actions['roles']) ? $actions['roles'] : null;
    }
}
```

In kernel, enable the 'roles' middleware:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
    'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
    'guest' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
    'roles' => 'App\Http\Middleware\CheckRole',
];
```

You will also need to set up a roles table, with some role data and then assign the relationships to the role on the User model.

The full code is available here: https://gist.github.com/amochohan/8cb599ee5dc0af5f4246

Hope this helps.

Comment: RoleTableSeeder.php where should put it?

Comment: That should go into your database/seeds directory. It's not essential for this system, it's just to set up a few example roles. As long as you create a role called 'Root' in your database you should be ok.

Comment: get this: Class 'App\Role' not found

Comment: You need to create a 'Role' model, something like: <?php namespace App; class Role extends Model{ ... }

Comment: Created but now get this error: ErrorException in User.php line 46:
Trying to get property of non-object
in User.php line 46
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Trying to get property of non-object', '/var/www/htdocs/ProjectMenager/app/User.php', '46', array('roles' => 'Admin')) in User.php line 46

Comment: Hard to debug without seeing your code. You'll need to put it somewhere for someone to take a proper look at.