# Developing more than one user accounts in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, authentication, filter, laravel-5

Note: There is no code to show or prove it, we just need a methodology to solve the problem before implementing the code to our code base.

We have more than one user for our fashion web (laravel app)

1. Guest (does not matter to this issue)
2. User (Fashion lovers/Customers/Clients)
3. Tailors (Fashion designers new/existing accounts in the platform)

The users(customers) can login and register to their application without no problem but our problem is how can we filter the two users(customers/tailors) such that when a user (tailor) logins to www.app.dev/tailor@dashboard (without access) it redirects to (www.app.dev/login) and when the user is a tailor it takes the user to tailors login page instead the user (customers) login, Do you understand me??

Comment: Assign them to groups, then check for group level when redirecting. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization might help

Comment: you can use middleware to check different user before login request

Answer (score 0):

check for following stackoverflow questions

[Can anyone explain Laravel 5.2 Multi Auth with example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614753/can-anyone-explain-laravel-5-2-multi-auth-with-example)

[How to use multi Auth in laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34490600/how-to-use-multi-auth-in-laravel-5-2)

[Multiple auth user types in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728456/multiple-auth-user-types-in-laravel-5)